# msck repair a big table take very long time

Tags: hive, hdfs, bigtable, hive-partitions

I have a daily ingestion of data into HDFS . From data into HDFS I generate Hive tables partitioned by date and another column. One day has 130G data. After generate the data, I run `msck repair`. Now every msck tasks more than 2 hours. In my mind, msck will scan the whole table data (we have about 200 days data) and then update metadata. My question is: is there a way let the msck only scan the last day data and then update the metadata to speed up the whole process? by the way there is no small files issue, I already merge the small files before msck.

Answer (score 0):

When you creating external table or doing repair/recover partitions with this configuration:

```
set hive.stats.autogather=true;
```

Hive scans each file in the table location to get statistics and it can take too much time.

The solution is to switch it off before create/alter table/recover partitions

```
set hive.stats.autogather=false;
```

See these related tickets: [HIVE-18743](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18743), [HIVE-19489,](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19489) [HIVE-17478](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17478)

If you need statistics, you can gather statistics only for new partitions if necessary using

```
ANALYZE TABLE [db_name.]tablename [PARTITION(partcol1[=val1], partcol2[=val2], ...)]  
  COMPUTE STATISTICS
```

See details here: [ANALYZE TABLE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev#StatsDev-ExistingTables%E2%80%93ANALYZE)

Also if you know which partitions should be added, use [ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions) - you can add many partitions in single command.